# What does "feet" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image][Context: Youtube Link: Time 3:02-3:10](https://youtu.be/FJmRQ5iTXKE?t=179)

> and my **feet** are not coming more than at the most **2 inches** off the groud for regular bounce, so somewhere in the range of **1 to 2 inches** is all that.

What does **"feet"** mean here? Does he mean **"heel"** not more than 2 inches off the ground or **"toe"** not more than 2 inches off the ground"? Because I think his **"heel"** are apparently 2 inches off the ground... If he meant **"toe"**, why didn't he use the word **"toe"** but "feet"?

Answer (score 0):

Feet just has the usual meaning. Check a picture dictionary if you are unsure. He could have said "toes" but as toes are the lowest part of the feet, saying "My feet are 1 inch off the ground" and "My toes are one inch off the ground" would have exactly the same meaning. Don't overthink this one. There is nothing deep or complex here.

Comment: He said his "feet" is not 2 inches off the groud. but "heel" are also part of a "feet".

Comment: So what. If I say "my feet are 2 inches off the ground" I mean "the lowest part of my feet"  He could even say "I am 2 inches off the ground" even though his head is part of him.